# How to make notification for action press "Home Button" [Objective-C]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I need to sign the classes to notify using `NSNotification` and `NSNotificationCentre` when the application goes in the background when the HOME button is pressed and the application close, each object needs to inform that application is closed in the console.

So I found the answer to my question:

for total application: 
in AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
// If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    NSLog(@"Sent to background by locking screen");
} else if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"kDisplayStatusLocked"]) {
        NSLog(@"Sent to background by home button/switching to other app");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Sent to background by locking screen");
    }
}
```

}

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
// Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    NSLog(@"Open an aplication from background");
}
```

}

but in my case, for using Notification for each class, I need to do this:

```
    - (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didEnterBackgroundNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterForegroundNotification:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];


    }
    return self;
}

    - (void) didEnterBackgroundNotification: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"This object goes to background");
}

- (void) willEnterForegroundNotification: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSLog(@"This object is alive");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no dedicated way to listen for presses to the home button, but when the app enters the background you can get notification from `applicationDidEnterBackground` in AppDelegate and before termination you can notification from `applicationWillTerminate` in AppDelegate.